# Fazer uma função assincrona aguardar por outra

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, assincronismo

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em JavaScript com Node.JS e Redis, porém, devido as funções assíncronas o loop termina antes das funções, o que causa a ordenação errada do array de resposta ou o time out no servidor.
Diante do meu problema, é possível fazer as funções esperarem umas pelas outras?
Qual seria um possível solução para o meu problema?

Código do que eu já fiz até o momento:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var redis = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient(32769, '192.168.99.100');

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

router.post('/UsuarioLogadoPossuiAcoes', function (req, res) {

    var templateKey = 'Usuario:' + req.body.token;

    var resposta = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.Acoes.length ; i++) {

        var Namespace = req.body.Acoes[i].split('.');
        var Verbo = Namespace.pop();
        Namespace = Namespace.join('.');
        var chave = templateKey + ':' + Namespace;

        client.exists(chave, function (err, existe) {

            if (existe == 1) {

                client.sscan(chave, 0, 'MATCH', Verbo, function (err, resultado) {

                    resposta[i] = (resultado[1].length > 0);
                    console.log(i + ' - ' + resposta[i]);
                    console.log(chave + '.' + Verbo);

                    //Verifica se as validações terminaram, encerra a conexão com o redis e responde a conexão
                    if (req.body.Acoes.length == resposta.length) {

                        client.end();
                        res.json(resposta);

                    }

                });

            } else {

                // Procura no banco relacional e faz o cache no redis

                resposta[i] = false;
                console.log(i + ' - ' + resposta[i]);

                //Verifica se as validações terminaram, encerra a conexão com o redis e responde a conexão
                if (req.body.Acoes.length == resposta.length) {

                    client.end();
                    res.json(resposta);

                }
            }
        });
    }    
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Olá, Mateus. Pode explicar melhor o que está fazendo e quais linhas você acredita serem a causa do problema? Talvez haja uma solução melhor do que parar toda a execução, já que assim você perde boa parte das vantagens de usar o NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, oque eu fiz para solucionar meu problema foi uma função recursiva com um callback e no callback dou a resposta. Atualmente isso esta resolvendo meu problema

Answer (score 3):

O ideal seria que tudo dentro do `for` ocorresse dentro de uma função separada, mas creio que apenas mudar isto:

```
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.Acoes.length ; i++) {
   //...
}
```

para:

```
req.body.Acoes.forEach(function(acao, i, Acoes) {
  //...
});
```

Resolveria seu problema. O loop termina antes das funções assíncronas acabarem, mas no segundo caso a variável de índice é contextualizada dentro do corpo da função, assim, mesmo após a função assíncrona acabar, o valor de `i` continuará o mesmo.

Lembrando que dentro da função do `forEach` você deixaria de usar `req.body.Acoes[i]` para se referenciar a cada item e usaria a parâmetro `acao` (ou o nome que preferir).

Referência para documentação do `forEach` no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).